# Как сделать, чтобы не объединялись блоки?

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Есть такой [код](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/3fzng/2/). Как сделать чтобы при добавлении нового блока (с изображением и текстом),  то есть код html будет уже такой:

```
<div>
  <img src="#" alt="здесь Ваша фотография" />
  <span>Здесь текст</span>
    <img src="#" alt="здесь Ваша фотография" />
  <span>Здесь текст</span>
</div>
```

эти блоки не объединялись? Что нужно дописать чтобы при любом количестве добавления блоков они были разные, то есть считались как отдельные, между ними был промежуток.
Здесь они просто склеиваются.
Спасибо!

Comment: @V_Pavelov благодаря вам узнал что редактор теперь теги игнорирует. Чтобы перенести `b` после `а` на новую строку поставьте после `a` два пробела и потом перенос строки...

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, Вам подойдет следующее:

```
    <div>
       <img src="#" alt="здесь Ваша фотография" />
       <span>Здесь текст</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="#" alt="здесь Ваша фотография" />
       <span>Здесь текст</span>
    </div>
```

А чтобы сделать отступ, используйте правило CSS [margin](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin)

Comment: спс. я уже сделал. http://jsfiddle.net/qHWLN/